# React Hooks: Uncaught TypeError: setData({...}) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm fairly new to React Hooks but I do have a decent understanding of how they work, or at least I thought I did.  In my component I'm trying to use `useState` in a similar manner as `setState` works but am coming across this error when trying to call my hook method `setData`:  `Uncaught TypeError: setData({...}) is not a function`

My component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import DispatcherModal from './DispatcherModal.js';
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner';

//Formats the DispatcherTable Information for each row
const DispatcherTable = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        updateClickedDispatchersRow: "",
        filterArray: "",
        User: null,
        DispatchersDB: [],
        Loading: true,
        ModalOpen: false,
        SubData: null,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;
        let username = localStorage.getItem('user');
        socket.emit('getUserByUsername', username, (user) => {
            if(!user){
                console.error('There was an issue validating user information.')
            }else{
                socket.emit('selectFromDispatchersForTM', (result) => {
                    if(mounted){
                        setData({...data, User: user[0], DispatchersDB: result, Loading: false})                     
                    }
                });
            }
        })

        return () => {
            mounted = false;
        }
    },[])

    const RefreshTableData = () => {
        socket.emit('selectFromDispatchersForTM', (result) => {
            setData({...data, DispatchersDB: result})
        });
    }

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setData({...data, filterArray: e.target.value.toLowerCase()})
    }

    const AddNewItemBtn = () => {
        if (data.User.UserType == 'admin') {
            setData({...data, updateClickedDispatchersRow: "", ModalOpen: true})
            
            (document.getElementById('myModal')).style.display = "block";
            (document.getElementById('modal_dispatchers')).style.display = "block";

        }
    }

    const RowClick = (e) => {
        let id = e.target.id.replace(e.target.id.substring(0, 4), '')
        let dispatcher_info = data.DispatchersDB.filter(e => e.UserID == id)[0]
        setData({...data, updateClickedDispatchersRow: id, SubData: dispatcher_info, ModalOpen: true})
        (document.getElementById('myModal')).style.display = "block";
        (document.getElementById('modal_dispatchers')).style.display = "block";
    }

    function RenderBody() {
        let dispatchersDB = (data.DispatchersDB).filter(obj => ((obj.Activity + " " + obj.Email + " " + obj.FullName + " " + obj.FirstName + " " + obj.LastName + " " + obj.PhoneNumber + " " + obj.UserType + " " + obj.Username + " " + obj.UserID).toLowerCase()).includes(data.filterArray));
        
        let rows = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < dispatchersDB.length; i++) {
            rows.push(
                <tr className="TableBodyRow" id={"DISP" + dispatchersDB[i].UserID} onClick={RowClick} key={i}>
                    <td className="tableData20" id={"DISP" + dispatchersDB[i].UserID} onClick={RowClick}>
                        {dispatchersDB[i].Username}
                    </td>

                    <td className="tableData20" id={"DISP" + dispatchersDB[i].UserID} onClick={RowClick}>
                        {dispatchersDB[i].UserType}
                    </td>

                    <td className="tableData20" id={"DISP" + dispatchersDB[i].UserID} onClick={RowClick}>
                        {dispatchersDB[i].FirstName} {dispatchersDB[i].LastName}
                    </td>

                    <td className="tableData20" id={"DISP" + dispatchersDB[i].UserID} onClick={RowClick}>
                        {dispatchersDB[i].PhoneNumber}
                    </td>

                    <td className="tableData20" id={"DISP" + dispatchersDB[i].UserID} onClick={RowClick}>
                        {dispatchersDB[i].Email}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        }


        return (

            <div className="TableBodyScrollingDiv">
                <table className="TableBodyContainer">
                    <tbody>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        );
    }

    function RenderMainBody(){
        let divtorender = null;

        if(data.Loading){
            divtorender = (
                <div style={{marginTop: '25%'}}>
                    <Spinner></Spinner>
                </div>
            )
        }else {
            divtorender = (
                <div style={{height: '100%'}}>

                    <div className="TitleBarContainer">
                        <h1 >Dispatchers Table</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div className="TopBarContainer">
                        <input type="text" className="TopBarSearchInput" placeholder="Search.." title="" onChange={onChange} />
                    </div>

                    <table className="TableHeaderContainer" style={{width: '100%'}}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th className="tableData20" id="TITL">Username</th>
                                <th className="tableData20" id="TITL">UserType</th>
                                <th className="tableData20" id="TITL">Name</th>
                                <th className="tableData20" id="TITL">Number</th>
                                <th className="tableData20" id="TITL">Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    {RenderBody()}

                    <div className="BottomBarContainer" id="AddDispatcherContainer">
                        {data.User.UserType == 'admin' ? <span><button className="RTIButton" id="AddNewItemBtn" onClick={AddNewItemBtn} style={{ float: 'right' }}>Add</button></span> : undefined}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return divtorender;
    }

    return(
        <div className="ViewedContentContainer" id="OpenContainer" >
            {RenderMainBody()}
        </div>
    )
}

export default DispatcherTable;
```

The issue arises when I try to use the method `RowClick` and also on the Add button.  What is odd is that when I call `setData` in `useEffect` I do not get this error.  Only after the component has mounted.  I've tried changing the RenderBody method to an arrow function but that did not work either.  This is a broad question to lookup on google so it was hard for me to find anyone who had the same issue.

If anyone has any suggestions, or can see what I'm doing wrong that would be very helpful.  TIA!

Comment: This is a general observation, and does not answer your question, but this pattern where you have these "functions inside your component that generate JSX" like RenderMainBody: that is an anti-pattern in react. Functions that generate JSX should be components themselves

Comment: @ColinD I appreciate the observation.  Is there a performance issue with doing it this way?  Or is there something else that this structure effects?

Comment: React is better able to optimize smaller components. Is this all the code? Is there any place where you're calling the result of `setData({...}})`, like `setData({...})(...)`?

Comment: @ColinD that makes sense I'm going to refactor some of my bad practices.  Yes this is all of the code that is using the ```setData``` method.

Comment: The issue is within the socket.emit in your useEffect inside the else block . setData will not be in the scope of the callback .

Comment: @Shyam ```setData``` in my useEffect is the only one that works so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Does the stack trace gives you line no of where this error is from ? I don't think the error is from the your other handlers . But I doubt the places where you have the setData within the `emit` .

Comment: @Shyam  Yes when I click on a row in my table it is pointing me to the one within the method of ```RowClick```

Answer (score 1):

alright, so after some trial and error I noticed that having a semicolon at the end of `setData({...})` is a must.  If you look at my `RowClick` method you will notice that I have the next line wrapped in parenthesis and react was reading the line as:

```
setData({...data, updateClickedDispatchersRow: id, SubData: dispatcher_info, ModalOpen: true})(document.getElementById('myModal')).style.display = "block";
```

instead of reading it as two seperate lines.  So by adding in the semicolon at the end of `setData` or getting rid of the unnecessary parenthesis in the next line, the error goes away.

Not sure if this is a bug or if it is setup to be this way, but I do find it a bit odd.

Comment: Reading about ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) might help you understand your mistake (never, ever, start a line with parentheses or brackets!). In this case, your parentheses around document.getElementById are redundant, so you can remove them and spare yourself a semicolon.

Comment: @Altareos well I was refactoring this component from the developer before me and that's how they had it set up, which I really didn't understand why it was set that way in the first place.  Now realizing that this is where the error was coming from I will be able to fix it in all of the other components that are structured this way as well.